# How can I make Mongoose (running on Node.js) run an arbitrary query string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have a table called "files" wherein each object has a name, a parent, and some other fields.  What I want to do is, given a filename, find the path to root (root occurs when parent is '').

I have a query that works perfectly when run in the Mongo terminal:

```
var currentFile = parent;
var queue = [];

while(currentFile !== '') {
    var file = db.files.find( { name: currentFile } );
    currentFile = file[0].parent;
    queue.push(currentFile);
}
```

Unfortunately, however, Mongoose does not allow (as far as I have seen from the documentation) arbitrary string queries.  I could do it if Mongoose allowed for synchronous queries, but I cannot seem to find that ability either.

**SOLVED**

After re-reading the first comment, I found that to achieve what I needed, I needed to add a callback to the parameters that gets called when currentFile is empty

```
if(currentFile === '') {
    callback();
else
    recursiveFunc(currentFile, callback);
```

I also added the field of 'path' in case I decide to be a little bit more efficient :)

Thank you guys for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a recursive function?

```
var queue = [];
var currentFile = parent;
function findStuff(currentFile) {
    File.findOne({name: currentFile}, function(err, file) {
        currentFile = file[0].parent;
        queue.push(currentFile);
        findStuff(currentFile)
    })
}
```

Also as or "arbitrary query string", I'm not sure what you mean. It's standard mongo syntax. If you want to hit the node-mongodb-native driver directly you can always do something like this. It's still async though.... https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native

```
File.collection.find({}, function(err, files) {});
```

What about something simpler? Sorry, I'm not fully understanding your intentions.

```
var queue = [];
var currentFile = parent;
File.find({name: currentFile}, function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
         queue.push(file.parent)
    })
})
```

Comment: How could I call this and ensure that the array that I get after the call contains all of the elements?

By "arbitrary query string," I mean send a string of BSON (with some JavaScript) to the MongoDB server, execute it, and get the results, a la MySQL.

Comment: ooooh. let me change it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could avoid this entirely by storing an additional field in your documents that contains the path to root - say, an array of ObjectId's called `path_to_root`.

Then when inserting a new document, just copy the parent's value for `path_to_root` and append the parent's `_id` to it, and use this as `path_to_root` for the newly inserted document.
With this strategy you could quickly query all the documents for the path back to root using a mongodb `$in` query.

Not sure if this could work for you without understanding the larger context, but just throwin it out there.